# ASP.NET MVC Web Api Help page routing

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, api, routes

Now by default ASP.NET MVC Web Api Help page accessible by `http://localhost:50784/Help` route I want to change it to `http://localhost:50784/Developers`. How could I make this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, there is an [area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(VS.100).aspx) called `Help` registered to your route configuration. You can change that to your custom name.

You will see a `HelpPageAreaRegistration.cs` file under `~/Areas/HelpPage` where we have the route registration. You can edit it to have your custom name

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "HelpPage_Default",
        "Developers/{action}/{apiId}",
        new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", apiId = UrlParameter.Optional });

    HelpPageConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
}
```

Comment: Shyju is right. The other way you can achieve what you are trying to do is to use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).